# PHP div repeating itself

Tags: php, html, slider

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me fix this script...It basically just calls either a slideshow if the file is an image, a vimeo player if it has a vimeo url, and an embedded swf if it is a flash file.

```
<div id='jessslide'>
    <?php
$photos=file("work.txt");
echo "<div id='slider-wrapper'>";
foreach($photos as $image){
$flag=0;
$item=explode("|",$image);
if($item[0]==$fields[0]){
$photo=trim($item[1]);

// check for Vimeo
if(strpos($photo, "vimeo.com") && $flag==0){
echo "<iframe src='$photo?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0' width='900' height='500'     frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>";
$flag=1;
}
// check for Flash
if(strpos($photo, ".swf") && $flag==0){
echo "<object id='myId' classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' width='900'     height='500'><param name='movie' value='$photo' />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='images/work/$photo' width='900' height='500'>
            <!--<![endif]-->
            <div>
            <h1>Alternative content</h1>
            <p><a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer'><img src='http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif' alt='Get Adobe Flash player' /></a></p>
            </div>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>";
$flag=1;
}
// If it's not Vimeo or Flash, then it must be a photo
if($flag==0){
echo "<div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'><img src='images/work/$photo' alt='' /></div>\n";
}
}
}
echo "</div>";
?>
  </div>
```

Everything works fine, however, the slideshow only displays 1 image. When viewing the generated source, this is what is displaying for the slideshow:

```
 <div id='jessslide'>
    <div id='slider-wrapper'><div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'><img src='images/work/sparklingsweet1.jpg' alt='' /></div>
<div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'><img src='images/work/sparklingsweet2.jpg' alt='' /></div>
<div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'><img src='images/work/sparklingsweet3.jpg' alt='' /></div>
<div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'><img src='images/work/sparklingsweet4.jpg' alt='' /></div>
<div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'><img src='images/work/sparklingsweet5.jpg' alt='' /></div>
<div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'><img src='images/work/sparklingsweet6.jpg' alt='' /></div>
<div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'><img src='images/work/sparklingsweet7.jpg' alt='' /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is what the correct working slideshow output should look like:

```
<div id='slider-wrapper'>
<div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'>
<img src='images/work/sparklingsweet1.jpg' alt='' />
<img src='images/work/sparklingsweet2.jpg' alt='' />
<img src='images/work/sparklingsweet3.jpg' alt='' />
<img src='images/work/sparklingsweet4.jpg' alt='' />
<img src='images/work/sparklingsweet5.jpg' alt='' />
<img src='images/work/sparklingsweet6.jpg' alt='' />
<img src='images/work/sparklingsweet7.jpg' alt='' />
</div>
</div>
```

So it seems to be a div issue...I'm not doing something right with the divs in the php. Anyone wanna be awesome and help me out with this silly div issue? :)

*There is only one div outside of the php script on the php page I have, which is the "jessslide".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id='jessslide'>
    <?php
    $photos=file("work.txt");
    foreach($photos as $image){
        $flag=0;
        $item=explode("|",$image);
        if($item[0]==$fields[0]){
            $photo=trim($item[1]);

            // check for Vimeo
            if(strpos($photo, "vimeo.com") && $flag==0):
                echo "<iframe src='$photo?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0' width='900' height='500'     frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>";
                $flag=1;

            // check for Flash
            elseif(strpos($photo, ".swf") && $flag==0):
                echo "<object id='myId' classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' width='900'     height='500'><param name='movie' value='$photo' />
                            <!--[if !IE]>-->
                            <object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='images/work/$photo' width='900' height='500'>
                            <!--<![endif]-->
                            <div>
                            <h1>Alternative content</h1>
                            <p><a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer'><img src='http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif' alt='Get Adobe Flash player' /></a></p>
                            </div>
                            <!--[if !IE]>-->
                            </object>
                            <!--<![endif]-->
                        </object>";
                $flag=1;

            // If it's not Vimeo or Flash, then it must be a photo
            else :
                $photoarray[] = $photo;
            endif;
        }
    }
    if (isset($photoarray)):
        echo "<div id='slider-wrapper'><div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'>";
        foreach ($photoarray as $photo):
            echo "<img src='images/work/$photo' alt='' />\n";
        endforeach;
        echo "</div></div>";
    endif;

    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh darn, it turns out that the vimeo player and swf are now inside of the slider! D:

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately the edited code makes it go a little crazy lol, it lists all of the filenames that I have in the .txt file :P

Comment: It's a bit hard to debug without looking at the output but I've made a few quick changes. It's very late here so no guarantees :-)

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for helping me out!! It works perfectly! :D You've made my day! Haha :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing but id is a unique identifier.  You can't have multiple elements on the same page with the same id.  I'd look there first to see if that's the source of your problem.  Most likely it's doing whatever it is you want on the very last div with the id of "slider" and all the rest are just being trashed in some way.